# How to add elements to a ListView?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to add an element to my ListView.  I tried with myAdapter.add() (see code below) since ArrayAdapter has an add() method.  But that didn't work.  What is the correct way to add elements to my ListView?

```
public class LinearLayoutDemo extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    private static final String[] items={"1", "2", "4", "8", "16", "32", "64"};
ListView myLV;
ArrayAdapter myAdapter;

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, items);
    myLV = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    myLV.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    myLV.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    // The following causes the program to fail:
    myAdapter.add("128");
}
```

Also, the program crashes if if I try myAdapter.clear().  Am I not using the ArrayAdapter correctly?

Comment: "But that didn't work", "Also, the program crashes". What does that mean? What happens? Also post the log output of any exceptions.

Comment: When I say it didn't work, I mean the program stops running with this error message on the device: Unfortunately com.example.mine has stopped.  Then the program exits.

Comment: @JB_User: I think I recall a similar question a while ago that ended up concluding that `ArrayAdapter.add()` doesn't work properly when it's passed an array, and to use a List instead. This can easily be done with `Arrays.asList()`.

Comment: Is there another way to add elements to a ListView?  Surely I'm not the only one trying to do this.

Comment: JB_User, that does the log say? When you look at the log, it should show a stacktrace of the crash. Do you know how to log? in the terminal: "adb logcat"

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I got it working with the ArrayList as you and Hoan suggested.  So, I'm not going to post the log, unless you want me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add to `items` and then call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. But the way you defined `items` as `final` you cannot add. If you want to add new element easily you should declare items as `ArrayList<String>`.

```
public class LinearLayoutDemo extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
private static List<String> items = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "4", "8", "16", "32", "64");
ListView myLV;
ArrayAdapter myAdapter;

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);

myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, items);
myLV = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
myLV.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
myLV.setAdapter(myAdapter);


items.add("128");
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I tried this and received lots of compiler errors:     [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /home/roaduser/src/ANDROID/MyProjects/ShoppingCartFrag/bin/classes
    [javac] /home/roaduser/src/ANDROID/MyProjects/ShoppingCartFrag/src/com/commonsware/android/linearpct/LinearLayoutDemo.java:28: illegal start of type
    [javac]     private static ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(){"1", "2", "4", "8", "16", "32", "64"};

Comment: You can't initialize an ArrayList like that. That's similar to how you initialize an Array, but Lists don't initialize like that. Try this: List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

Answer (score 0):

You need to call:

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

on the adapter after adding the elements to notify on any changes in adapter's data set, But you can't change your data set after creation of `Array`. use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: I added this call into my code.  It still isn't working for me.  I get this error message: Unfortunately com.example.mine has stopped.

Comment: post full stack trace in your question.

Comment: What do you mean by a full stack trace?  The output of 'adb logcat'?

Comment: yes, but as been said, change your array: String[] items={"1", "2", "4", "8", "16", "32", "64"}; to arraylist. Array is static and you can't add item to it.